# Можно ли сделать js-библиотеку, которая подключала бы полифилы в зависимости от browserslist?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel

Предположим, хочу я написать JS-библиотеку реализующую некую функциональность. Для некоторых браузеров (ie11), для работы необходимо подключить несколько полифилов (CustomEvent, Element.closest и несколько кастомных реализаций).
Вопрос. Можно ли как-нибудь организовать сборку js-бандла, в зависимости от текущих поддерживаемых браузеров, прописанных где-нибудь в browserslist.rc, чтобы в бандл не попадали полифилы, которые не нужны?
Знаю, что [babel умеет это делать совместно с core-js](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env.html), но как настроить подобное со своими полифилами?

Comment: А зачем нужны свои полифилы - чем стандартные не угодили?

Comment: стандартные - это core-js, который полифилит только ES, например стандартного Element.closest полифила в составе нет.